# prevent chown/chmod access denied errors with cifs mount

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mount, cifs

I have a user directory mounted to ubuntu 12.04 with cifs.  /etc/fstab contains a line;

```
//cb/share /home/cb cifs user=ubuntu,password=abc123,uid=cb,gid=users 0 0
```

The share mounts and works fine except for chown/chmod commands, which fail with;

```
$ sudo touch /home/cb/foo
$ sudo chown cb /home/cb/foo
chown: changing ownership of `/home/cb/foo': Permission denied
```

Forget that cifs is squashing uid and gid to the correct values (cb:users) already.  There are some pre-existing scripts and utilities I need to use which fail because of the non-zero exit status returned by chown/chmod.

I naively tried mounting elsewhere (/mnt/cb), and then using bindfs to re-mount it, but this didn't work either.

```
sudo bindfs -o perms=0750,mirror=cb,group=users /mnt/cb /home/cb
```

Note, the only solution I'm looking for here is some way to configure the server/mount so that chmod/chown will fail quietly - i.e., return zero exit status.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the trivial answer is to preempt the real `chmod` and `chown` with other programs
that do not fail.  These can be scripts.  In `/home/cab/bin` (or any other convenient directory
that you have full access to), create scripts called `chmod` and `chown` that say just

```
#!/bin/sh
```

You can add `exit 0` if you want, but `0` will be the default exit status
if the script doesn’t do anything. 
And then, of course, add `/home/cab/bin` to the beginning of your `PATH` environment variable.

If you want to be able to `chmod` and `chown` when you can, make the scripts say
**[Edit]**

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/"$(basename "$0")" "$@"
exit 0
```

replacing `/bin` with the directory that the real `chmod` and `chown` are in. 
This executes the real command with the arguments to the script,
and then exits with a status of 0 regardless of the exit status of the program.

And since the two scripts are identical
(as long as the real `chmod` and `chown` commands are in the same directory on your system),
you can write one and make the other a link to it.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to detect whether a file/dir is mounted? Then I could protect the call to the real chown/chmod.

Comment: I’m not sure exactly what you mean, but try looking at `$(df "$filename")`.